# How to run a function with a setTimeout() callback inside iframe when this setTimeout() calls another setTimeout() in parent?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically created iframe on my page. Like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("id","myIframe");
iframe.src = "iframePage.html";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Inside the "iframePage.html", I have the same scriptfile.js that runs on mainPage.html. So, I can call all the functions inside one or another page.

In this scriptfile.js, I have this function that is called by a button on "iframePage.html". The function removes the iframe from DOM in 1 second! Just like this:

```
function closeAndRemoveIframe() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      var myIframe = window.parent.document.getElementById("myIframe");
      myIframe.parentNode.removeChild(myIframe);
   },1000);
}
```

Ok. 
But I added to this function a call to another function. But this function contains a setTimeout that generates a 3 second delay.

Just like this:

```
function closeAndRemoveIframe() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      var myIframe = window.parent.document.getElementById("myIframe");
      myIframe.parentNode.removeChild(myIframe);
      myNewFunction();
   },1000);
}
```

The problem is:
This new function has a longer runtime setTimeout (3000 ms).

```
function myNewFunction() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Hello world");
   },3000);
}
```

The iframe is the one calling the "myNewFunction ()" function. And once it is removed from the DOM after 1 second, the new function doesn't happen because it has a 3 second delay!

The only solution I found was to put the same time in the setTimeout of the first function! But this is not the desirable behavior!

So, is there any way to solve this without having to increase the settimeout time of the first function?

P.s: I'm using **vanilla JS**.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried moving the `myNewFunction` call before the `removeChild` function call?